# Arduino: Parse data from water sensor to web using GSM Shield

Tags: arduino, gsm

Good Day, I`m newbie in Arduino.

I have the Arduino uno, gsm shield, and water sensor. I would like to get data from water sensor and parse it to my website and store in database. I would like to use GSM shield. Can I do that?

I would like to know alghoritm how to implement this funtionality.
Anyway, thank you!

Comment: How do you store data in your website? I did something with a GSM modem by using a PHP page which wrote to a mySQL database the parameters sent through a GET request. This way I just had to call the page with some parameters ("mydomain.com/mypage.php?myparam1=value&myparam2=othervalue") and they were stored.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first you might know the rules right? Here on StackOverflow we are asking questions about not-working situations (bugs, mis-working feature,..and so on...). Please try to solve the issue by yourself next time through google and then ask for a problem of connectivity, code questions or whatever.

I know some great turorial as I did one myself back in the days : http://comoyo.github.io/blog/2013/08/01/m2m_adventures/

Regards,